# Safari Duplicating XML Node Data in Jquery

Tags: jquery, xml, safari

I have the following javascript code:

```
$(xml).find("question").each(function(){ 

if($(this).attr("id") == stage){                                      

    rule1 = $(this).find("sentence[id='1']").text();
    rule2 = $(this).find("sentence[id='2']").text();

}
                                      });
```

I then use .innerHTML to paste the text into a div in a html document.
This process works perfectly in all common browsers apart from Safari, where sentence 2 is being duplicated in the div.

*EDIT* Thanks to Frédéric's comment I was able to modify my existing XML and code to get this working in Safari. *EDIT*

Old XML:

```
<test>
 <question id="1">
  <sentence id="1">Even Odd Odd</sentence>
  <sentence id="2">8 3 5</sentence>
 </question>
 <question id="2">
  <sentence id="1">Odd Odd Odd</sentence>
  <sentence id="2">5 1 7</sentence>
 </question>
 <question id="3">
  <sentence id="1">Even Even Even</sentence>
  <sentence id="2">9 7 3</sentence>
</question>
</test>
```

New XML:

```
<test>
 <question id="q1">
  <sentence id="q1s1">Even Odd Odd</sentence>
  <sentence id="q1s2">8 3 5</sentence>
 </question>
 <question id="q2">
  <sentence id="q2s1">Odd Odd Odd</sentence>
  <sentence id="q2s2">5 1 7</sentence>
 </question>
 <question id="q3">
  <sentence id="q3s1">Even Even Even</sentence>
  <sentence id="q3s2">9 7 3</sentence>
</question>
</test>
```

My output for question 1 for example, would be Even Odd Odd (sentence 1)

8 3 58 3 5 (sentence 2)

Has anyone experienced anything similar to this, and could suggest a fix/workaround?

Thanks for your time.

*EDIT* Thanks Frédéric! *EDIT*

Comment: `id` attributes must be unique in an XML document. I'd suggest you use something like `q1`, `q2`, ..., `qN` for questions and `q1s1`, `q1s2`, ..., `qNsM` for sentences.

Comment: Hi Frédéric!  This was the solution!  I can't seem to mark your comment as an answer but I upvoted it!  Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

If you can't change XML source and if your IDs not corresponding to nodes index order (like my case), first get the index of your node with find('data[id=XX]').index(), and access to the text() function with eq() search. So :

```
$(this).find("sentence").eq($(this).find("sentence[id='2']").index()).text();
```

Hope this help.